# ORDER BY a String which contains a number

Tags: soql, string, orderitem

I'm trying to 'ORDER BY' a String field which contains numbers. It orders like this:

1
10
2
3
...

I've tried whith LPAD, VALUE, *1, but nothing works.

THANKS all for ur help!

Comment: CAST doesnt work btw

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two possible options I can think of right now:

First:

- Populate a map based on your query results, use this field as Integer key (use Integer.valueOf)
- Convert the keySet into a list and apply sort
- Iterate the list and fetch the map for results in sequence

Second:

- Add a formula field with return type as number and use it in ORDER BY clause.